# Selenium не работает с Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

С недавнего времени перестал работать selenium с Chrome.

Скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лог:

```
FAILED (errors=1)

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SBogdanov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\Users\SBogdanov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\Users\SBogdanov\PycharmProjects\TestsMts\Cardcredit.py", line 25, in test_user_cards_week_credit
    driver.get('https://site-pred1.mbrd.ru/chastnim-licam/karti/')
  File "C:\Users\SBogdanov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 324, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\SBogdanov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 310, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\SBogdanov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 466, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\SBogdanov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 490, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\SBogdanov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\SBogdanov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\SBogdanov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\SBogdanov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Перепробовал все, что нашел в инете и никак.

Comment: драйвер обновить пробовали?

Comment: @Andrew Bystrov Да, обновлял и в коде пытался отключать... никак

Comment: А скрин и ошибка как-то связаны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я тоже сталкивался точь в точь с этой проблемой, решилось так:
- Обновил хромдрайвер до последней версии
- Обновил хром до последней версии

Comment: Ну если бы проблема была в этом - то хром бы не открывался.

Comment: хром таки бы открывался, но в урле было бы "data;" - в точности как на скрине